# How to combine two columns into one in R, so that each value in the second column becomes every other value in the first column?

Tags: r, transform, donut-chart

I have the following dataset:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
detach(package:plyr)    
library(dplyr)

position <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F")
level <- c("P", "S", "J", "J", "P", "S", "S", "S")
car <- c("yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes")
car.data <- data.frame(position, level, car)

percent_car <- car.data %>%
  group_by(position) %>%
  summarise (car_yes = sum(car == "yes"), car_no = sum(car == "no")) %>%
  mutate(yes_perc = car_yes/(car_yes + car_no), no_perc = car_no/(car_yes + car_no))
percent_car
```

with the output being:

```
    position car_yes car_no yes_perc no_perc
  <chr>      <int>  <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A              1      1      0.5     0.5
2 B              0      1      0       1  
3 C              0      1      0       1  
4 D              0      1      0       1  
5 E              1      0      1       0  
6 F              1      1      0.5     0.5
```

My goal ist to create donut charts from this dataset and for that I would need the data in a form in which each position has two rows- one for the people in the position who have a car and one for people, who doesn´t. Also I want to calculate the ymax and the ymin for each row:

```
 Position yes_no car_yes_no yes_no_perc  ymax  ymin
   <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A       yes         1       0.5        0.5   0    
 2 A       no          1       0.5        1     0.5    
 3 B       yes         0       0          0     0    
 4 B       no          1       1          1     0    
 5 C       yes         0       0          0     0    
 6 C       no          1       1          1     0    
 7 D       yes         0       0          0     0    
 8 D       no          1       1          1     0    
 9 E       yes         1       1          0     0    
10 E       no          0       0          1     0    
11 F       yes         1       0.5        0.5   0    
12 F       no          1       0.5        1     0.5
```

Currently I am creating the second dataset in Excel. Do you know a way how I can directly create such a dataset in R?

Thanks!

Comment: You would want to `rbind` the datasets after you've added the `yes_no_car` column, then `arrange` by `position` and `yes_no_car`.

Comment: I can't understand what you search for. You made an effort of providing an example with training data, which is fine, but your question has some things that seems unclear to me (min of what ? You just counted cars among categories). Though, if I stick to the title of the question alone, maybe you'll be interested by pivot_longer in the package tidyr ? by example %>%pivot_longer(c(car_yes,car_no),names_to="yes_no",values_to = "car_yes_no") will reunite the two columns car yes and car_no to one column of values and one column of names. But I don't know if that's what you search for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully sure what your logic is for the `ymin`/`ymax` but this is the general idea, run it by line to see what's happening.

```
percent_car %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "key", values_to = "value", -position) %>%
  mutate(
    yes_no = str_extract(key, "yes|no"),
    key = str_remove_all(key, "yes|no|_")
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value) %>%
  arrange(position) %>%
  mutate(
    ymax = if_else(yes_no == "yes", perc, 1),
    ymin = if_else(yes_no == "yes", 0, 1-perc)
      
    )
  )
```

`case_when` will be your friend if the `if_else` needs to be nested

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly!! :) And you guessed the logic for ymin/ymax correctly as well!